# why does the vm_area_struct have start_code, end_code field?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

in linux, the vm_area_struct contains fields like start_code, end_code.
but a task has an mm_struct and that mm_struct has many vm_area_struct list.(see figure)
A task will have only one code area and data area, but why does the vm_area_struct has those start_code, end_code fields? Do the values belonging to the same mm_struct all have the same values for start_code and end_code?
(figure borrowed from http://esos.hanyang.ac.kr/tc/2015gradproject2/i/entry/2)

[image: mmu_struct and vm_area_struct (from http://esos.hanyang.ac.kr/tc/2015gradproject2/i/entry/2)]

Comment: `struct vm_area_struct` doesn't have `start_code`, `end_code`, etc. It has `vm_start` and `vm_end` pointing to the start and end of an `mmap`ed region.

Comment: ah, my mistake. correct, start_code, end_code appear in mm_struct which is what I expect. thank you! (I think I should delete this question soon.)